# Название салата должно быть в кавычках?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Вот конкретный пример. Нужно ли названия блюд писать в кавычках?

> Салаты Лемберг и Теплый вечер.

В каких случаях нужно использовать кавычки в названиях блюд при составлении меню.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Кавычек можно избежать, однако выделение названий тем или иным способом необходимо.*

Салаты ЛЕМБЕРГ и ТЕПЛЫЙ ВЕЧЕР / Салаты ***Лемберг*** и ***Тёплый вечер*** / *Салаты* Лемберг *и* Тёплый вечер.

Для акцидентной продукции предела разнообразия способов выделения не существует.